# External mapping file for URL Rewrite with Tomcat rewrite.config file

Tags: url-rewriting, tomcat9

is there a way to tell Tomcat to read information from an external file?

I have some friendly URL rewrites for my IIS website which successfully read data from a mapping file. When a request is made matching the first part of the rule in the mappingurl.txt file the corresponding id is read from the same file and passed onto the app server.

For example in .htaccess file I am using these two lines:
*RewriteMap mapfile txt:mappingurl.txt*
*RewriteRule ^series/([^?/]+)$ /index/?id=${mapfile:$1}*

Thanks to Tony's helpful article here https://tonyjunkes.com/blog/a-brief-look-at-the-rewrite-valve-in-tomcat-8/ I could do the rewrites on my Tomcat site but I would like to remove all the mapping and place it into an external file which could be generated grammatically.

What would be the syntax to do the same map inside the Tomcat's rewrite.config file?
TIA!